# quick question about the differentiable linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra done right, the author defined $D:P(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P(\mathbb{R})$ with $f \mapsto f'$ where $P(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of polynomials $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. He states that $D$ is a linear map, which I understand. Also, it seems that $D$ is bijective.

(Note, $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of polynomials of degree 3 at most)My question that I am confused about is that $D_3: P_3(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear map? The reason why I question this is that the author has another theorem i.e. Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, $\dim V = \dim W < \infty$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Then, $T \text{ invertible} \iff T \text{ injective} \iff T \text{ surjective}$. However, $D_3$ is (I think) is injective, but it's clearly not surjective because I can never get a polynomial with degree 3.

Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: $D_3$ is not injective. For instance $D_3(1)=D_3(0)=0$. $D_3$ is linear, yes.

Comment: oh wait im stupid